# Поэтапный опросник на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Имея такой код я хочу сделать логику опросника подобную этой: https://nasty6.typeform.com/to/BgJEd2 , то есть чтобы при вводе в поле какой-либо информации и нажатии на Enter происходил переход на другой input, а неактивные поля становились затемненными как в примере. У кого-то есть идеи как это реализовать или же где можно посмотреть? Заранее спасибо огромное Вам!!!

```html
                    <div class="interview__input-wrapper">
                        <div class="interview__item">
                            <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Ваше имя?</div>
                            <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Моё имя.." autofocus>
                        </div>
                        <div class="interview__item">
                            <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Сколько Вам?</div>
                            <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Мой возраст..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="interview__item">
                            <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Какой стаж?</div>
                            <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Мой стаж..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="interview__item">
                            <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Сильные стороны?</div>
                            <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Мои сильные стороны..">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: я понимаю, что этот вопрос был задан давно, но хотел уточнить, у Вас случайно исходный код не сохранился? А то мне дали задание реализовать опросник https://mrqz.me/5bba69f9255a060044653c65 - пример это. Заранее спасибо

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/526410)

Comment: Я использовал решение, которое подсказал petrichor (Отмеченный верный ответ в этом вопросе). При желании вы можете доработать код под свои потребности, но мне этого хватило. За что выражаю огромную благодарность petrichor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

[Статья про обработчики событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events)

Обработчик нужно будет удалить, когда он больше не нужен.

UPD. Похоже, что e.keyCode лучше заменить на key  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43418287/8579902

```
 var key = e.key;
    if (key === 'Enter')
```

[Документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

```js
//Все поля
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".interview__item input"); 

inputs.forEach(function(input, i) {
  //Следим за нажатием кнопки
  input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    //Если нажат Enter
    if (key === 13) {
        //<input disabled .... />
        input.disabled = true;
        if(i < inputs.length - 1)
           //Переводим фокус на следующее поле
           inputs[i + 1].focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="interview__input-wrapper">
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Ваше имя?</div>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="interview__input change__input"
      placeholder="Моё имя.."
      autofocus
    />
  </div>
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Сколько Вам?</div>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="interview__input change__input"
      placeholder="Мой возраст.."
    />
  </div>
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Какой стаж?</div>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="interview__input change__input"
      placeholder="Мой стаж.."
    />
  </div>
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">
      Сильные стороны?
    </div>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="interview__input change__input"
      placeholder="Мои сильные стороны.."
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как возможно затемнять другие элементы если они не активны?

Comment: @Dan то есть поле должно быть затемнено, пока на него не кликнули?

Comment: Да, и еще чтобы поле доскролливалось и пользователь не делал этого сам, в примере 4 вопроса, а что если их будет 50?

Comment: Тогда можно изначально все поля сверстать `disabled`, повесить на них обработчик `focus` (чтобы учесть и тап с девайсов и переключение по полям с использованием tab), когда событие происходит, ставить `disabled = false`. А для скролла, при срабатывании обработчика нажатия `Enter`, скроллить к следующему элементу с помощью [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Comment: Как альтернатива `disabled` - изначально `background` поля ставить затемненный, а при клике добавлять класс, в котором прописан `background` активного поля.

Comment: А у вас когда прошелся по всем input нельзя вернуться в другие и изменить их значение, как это можно исправить? Пользователь ведь может захотеть изменить их значение

Comment: @Dan посмотрите предыдущий комментарий, disabled можно просто не использовать, если вам не нужно такое поведение

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался!